# Can't get the hover to work on navigation anchors

Tags: html, css, hover

Can't get the hover on menu links to work. I'm using Xampp for local remote testing.

```
.menu ul>li a:hover{
        color: blue;
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
```

I've tried different selectors, etc... nothing seems to work
here is the code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-image: url("../images/header.jpg");
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.about {
  background-image: url("../images/bellow_header.jpg");
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* here starts the styles for the NAvigation bar */

#logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block !important;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  margin: 1rem auto 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
}

.active a {
  color: #CC5200!important;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.menu a {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0.3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/*by default on mobile the navigation isn't visible*/

.menu li {
  display: none;
  color: black;
}

.menu .icon {
  order: 99;
  display: block;
}

.menu.menuOpen {
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #161415;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
}


/*moving the icon to the top-right corner*/

.menu.menuOpen .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.menu.menuOpen li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}


/*tablets */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
  /* Styles */
  /*hidding the icon*/
  .menu .icon {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
  }
  .menu ul>li a:hover {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  #logo {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}


/*Landscape making the background look good */

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* Landscape styles */
  header {
    height: 120%;
  }
}


/*laptops */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  /* Styles */
  #logo {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 3rem;
    left: 4rem;
  }
}


/*large screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  /* Styles */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>StyleTravel-Home</title>
  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>

  <meta name="description" content="StyleTravel is one of the most used services for booking HighEnd Sejours">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Sejours,StyleTravel,HighEnd,Expensive,Exotic">
  <meta name="author" content="Bogdan Mihalca">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- normalize -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <!--layout styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Google fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html" id="logo">StyleTravel</a>
    <nav class="menu" id="myMenu">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myResponsiveHamburger()">
            <i id="hamb-icon" class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="about"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works fine in the snippet...

Comment: Yeah, but in all browsers is not.

Comment: Ask a question about your specific problem. Describe the behaviour in more detail than "not working" (what does it do? what should it do?). Be specific about which browsers work as you expect and which don't.

Comment: Sorry if i was poorly specific! I'll try my best next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#logo {
font-size: 2.5rem;
text-decoration: none;
/* display: block !important; */
```

}

Your hover is absolutely fine but one mistake!  `display: block !important;` this is what you put on  and it is stretching and took all the visible width. So when you hovers over the links it's actually not hover over them! If you remove or unset the style it will work!

Though your hover is not looking great but it will hover if you remove the code! Here is my [demo](https://codepen.io/mobarak/pen/BezpXV)

[image]

```
#logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block !important;  /* Remove this ans code will work!*/
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  margin: 1rem auto 0 auto;
  font-family: "Pacifico", cursive;
  outline: 1px solid red;  /* for demonestration */
  background: #3333;     /* for demonestration */
}
```

Just Remove the commented styles and it will be fine.